# SharePoint 2007: How to get List URL from List Name using Web services?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have a MOSS List, how can I get the URL for the list from the List name only using web service methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the next poor sucker working without documentation:

```
/// <summary>
        /// The SharePoint Web Service: Lists.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly sharepoint.lists.Lists wsLists = new sharepoint.lists.Lists();

private string GetListUrlFromName(string listName)
        {
            XmlNode node = wsLists.GetList(listName);
            return node.Attributes["RootFolder"].Value; 
        }
```

Comment: :-) Yes, the "RootFolder" is nearly always the answer for Lists.